# Populate Excel fields based on values

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I need column B & C to populate based on the data in Column D. Corporate Credit = CCD Credit. Corporate Debit = CCD Debit. Payroll = PPD Credit. For example:

Column D=
Corporate Credit
Corporate Debit
Payroll

Column B should populate as:
CCD
CCD
PPD

Column C should populate as:
Credit
Debit
Credit

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quickie version:

```
Sub fillIn()
For i= 1 to 65000
    If cells(i,4) = "Corporate Credit" Then
       cells(i,2) = "CCD"
       cells(i,3) = "Credit"
    ElseIf cells(i,4) = "Corporate Debit" Then
       cells(i,2) = "CCD"
       cells(i,3) = "Debit"  
    ElseIf cells(i,4) = "Payroll" Then
       cells(i,2) = "PPD"
       cells(i,3) = "Credit" 
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```